# How to see older changes than available in recent changes?

Tags: mediawiki

We have a hosted mediawiki running, where we only have limited access - so I can change files on the server and query the database, but do not have a console for executing scripts.

Now I need to get a list of changed pages of the last 6 month, which are only partly available via recent changes, since, as I understood, entries older than a certain time range are purged from the database.

So how can I either select the changes via SQL or use an extension which can list those without the need of the recent pages table?

Comment: Are you looking only for edits or for other kinds of changes that are in the recentchanges table?

Comment: @svick: I'm looking for edited articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use [the `revision` table](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aRevision_table) for this, it contains every (non-deleted) revision ever made to the wiki.

Comment: I saw that this table links to page table which holds the edited page I needed in my case, so this answer is accepted. Nevertheless, I added an own answer with the specific statement.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested how to use the revision + page table as suggested by svick, here's the statement to start with:

```
SELECT date_format( r.rev_timestamp, '%d.%m.%y' ) , cast( p.page_title AS char )
FROM revision r
JOIN page p ON ( r.rev_page = p.page_id )
ORDER BY r.rev_timestamp DESC
```